# #1054 - Unknown column in 'on clause' join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having this error :

> 1054 - Unknown column 't0.DESTINATION_ID' in 'on clause'

when running this query:

```
SELECT t0.ID,
       t0.DESTINATION_ID,
       t0.PRODUCT_ID,
       t0.ITEM_ID,
       t4.NAME,
       t4.CURRENTVALUE
FROM   ITEM t3,
       ITEM t2,
       PORTABLESENSOR t1,
       VIV_VIVIENNEITEM t0,
       PROD_PRODUCT_PROPERTY t5
       INNER JOIN PROPERTY AS t4
               ON (t4.ID = t5.properties_ID)
WHERE  ((((t1.ISSUED = 1)
          AND (t2.ID = t3.ID))
         AND (t0.PRODUCT_ID IN (2961)))
        AND (((t2.ID = t0.ITEM_ID)
              AND (t2.DTYPE = 'Item'))
             AND ((t3.ID = t1.ITEM_ID)
                  AND (t3.DTYPE = 'Item'))))
       AND (NAME = 'ColoreFornitore'
             OR (NAME = 'Modello')
             OR (NAME = 'DescrizioneColorefornitore'))
```

I know similar posts have been submitted before but I'm not able to resolve the problem. Can someone please help me find out what the problem is?

Comment: there is no t0.DESTINATION_ID' in 'on clause'. you sure you are in right query?

Comment: can you show us the execution result of DESCRIBE `VIV_VIVIENNEITEM`

Comment: Mixing join syntax types does not make for easy reading...

Comment: there is no 't0.DESTINATION_ID' in your query. At least I can't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a documented problem that occurs when you mix implicit join syntax with explicit join syntax in MySQL.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause for multiple tables.

You can fix this by replacing the commas with `cross join`:

```
FROM   ITEM t3 cross join
       ITEM t2 cross join
       PORTABLESENSOR t1 cross join
       VIV_VIVIENNEITEM t0 cross join
       PROD_PRODUCT_PROPERTY t5
       INNER JOIN PROPERTY AS t4
               ON (t4.ID = t5.properties_ID)
```

It is even better to use `join` and put the conditions in the `where` clause in `on` clauses.

The documentation on this issue is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

> INNER [CROSS] JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the
>   absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between
>   the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table
>   is joined to each and every row in the second table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information
>   about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.